# How to arrange the row data in columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pivot rows as columns.

The scenerio as below

```
users table
-----------------------------------
id  name            role

5   test ueser1     student
6   test user2      student

applications table
-----------------------------------
id  user_id app_type    app_content

1   5       Facebook    FB test data
2   5       Twitter     Tw test data
3   5       Linkedin    LD test data
4   5       Youtube     Y test data
```

A user can have many applications (One to Many relationship) so i put it in rows.

```
Expected Result
-----------------------------------
user_id     name          Facebook       Twitter        Linkedin       Youtube  

5           test ueser1   FB test data   Tw test data   LD test data   Y test data
```

Please provide a better solution to get same result.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pivot your data. MySQL doesn't provide a pivot function, but you could simulate it this way:

```
SELECT
  users.id,
  users.name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN app_type='Facebook' THEN app_content END) Facebook,
  MAX(CASE WHEN app_type='Twitter'  THEN app_content END) Twitter,
  MAX(CASE WHEN app_type='Linkedin' THEN app_content END) Linkedin,
  MAX(CASE WHEN app_type='Youtube'  THEN app_content END) Youtube
FROM
  applications INNER JOIN users
  ON applications.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY
  users.id,
  users.name
```